# What is the purpose of the threadfence intrinsic in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I have gone through many forum posts and the NVIDIA documentation,  but I couldn't understand what `__threadfence()` does and how to use it. Could someone explain what the purpose of that intrinsic is?

Answer (score 59):

Normally, there are no guarantee that if one block writes something to global memory, the other block will "see" it. There is also no guarantee regarding the ordering of writes to global memory, with an exception of the block that issued it.

There are two exceptions:

- atomic operations - those are always visible by other blocks
- threadfence

Imagine, that one block produces some data, and then uses atomic operation to mark a flag that the data is there. But it is possible that the other block, after seeing the flag, still reads incorrect or incomplete data.

The `__threadfence` function, coming to the rescue, ensures the ordering. All writes before it really happen before all writes after it, as seen from other blocks.

Note that the `__threadfence` function doesn't necessarily need to stall the current thread until its writes to global memory are visible to all other threads in the grid. Implemented in this naive way, the `__threadfence` function could hurt performance severely.

As an example, if you do something like:

1. store your data
2. `__threadfence()`
3. atomically mark a flag

it is guaranteed that if the other block sees the flag, it will also see the data.

Further reading: Cuda Programming Guide, Chapter [B.5](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions) (as of version 11.5)

Comment: How about __syncthreads(), does that guarantee that memory accesses by any thread in the block will be visible to all threads in the block?

Comment: `__syncthreads()` is stronger than `__threadfence_block()`. After `__syncthreads()` you have a guarantee that all shared/global memory writes before the barrier are visible by all threads after the barrier. However, `__syncthreads()` has an effect on a block only and no guarantees are given between threads of different blocks.

Comment: L1 from other SMs will be coherent with the data stored? Or do you still need to specify global scope loads (L1-non-cacheable)?

Comment: Don't `__syncthreads` and `__threadfence_block` only concern shared memory?

Comment: @user2023370 No. `__syncthreads` and `__threadfence_block` do ensure that all previous global changes by the given block are visible for all threads in that block. This is however less common use case for syncthreads, as usually you want to use shared memory for that kind of thread communication.

Comment: B.2.4 is now: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#managed

Comment: @LuoJigao Updated the chapter B.5 to include a link. I don't remember what was B.2.4 when I wrote it 10 years ago, I removed it not to cause confusion.