# cuda threadfence

Tags: synchronization, cuda, gpgpu

I'm writing a code that must perform an inter-block synchronization (the sum of N dimensions and other memory transfer operations). When I increment the dimension of the problem the result is wrong.

I am making the synchronization with `__threadfence()` and the first dimensions(N<192) that's ok, but if I insert other `__threadfence()` in the piece of code, the result is correct for more dimensions.

One `threadfence()` is not sufficient to synchronize? Aditional, the data result is used in the same block.

In the Programming guide the information indicate that`threadfence` wait for all memory spaces are ready (shared and global)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't think there is enough information in your question for someone to be able to give a good reply. Have you checked the section on `__threadfence()` in the CUDA C Programming Guide to see if it works the way you expect it to?

Comment: Please provide example code for your problem.

Answer (score 12):

There is no nice way to perform synchronization between blocks. You can either have a hacky approach with spin-waiting and eating up your GPU memory bandwidth, or you can terminate your kernel and start a new one.

`__threadfence()` is *not* for synchronization between blocks. `__threadfence()` is used to halt the current thread until all previous writes to shared and global memory are visible by other threads. It does not halt nor affect the position of other threads though!

You can check these questions:

- [cuda block synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404992/cuda-block-synchronization)
- [CUDA __threadfence()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232689/cuda-threadfence/5233737#5233737)

Comment: thanks for your answer. But in my problem only one block process generate a global result, its in this point where dont understand the function threadfence. if the result only is afected by one block the wait for result is unnecesary. The reason for this method is generate the best performance because a calling of kernel is iterative and should allocate dinamic memory .

Comment: @CygnusX1: Suppose all threads in a kernel execution are executing some write operation to global memory, and we don't want to proceed until all the writes are visible to all threads. Wouldn't having `__threadfence()` called by all threads following the write ensure synchronization?

Comment: No. `__threadfence()` only guarantees that the *current* thread won't proceed until the all previous changes of current thread to global memory are visible by other threads. Other threads may however try to read from the same memory cells before that happened, read old data and continue executing beyond `__threadfence()`.

Answer (score 3):

Cooperative groups will allow for synchronization between different blocks in the same kernel.  It's really easy to use now, too.

```cpp
#include <cooperative_groups.h>
namespace cg = cooperative_groups;

// and then in your code
cg::grid_group grid = cg::this_grid();
grid.sync(); // All threads in all blocks must run this line
```

Every thread in every block in the entire kernel must run that `grid.sync()`.
Execution of the next line will continue only after all threads have run that one.

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cooperative-groups