# naive cuda kernel for ReduceL2 operator

Tags: python, c++, numpy, cuda, reduce

I am trying to implement a cuda kernel for the operator [ReduceL2](https://onnx.ai/onnx/operators/onnx__ReduceL2.html) for educational purpose. For example, I have a 3-d tensor with shape `400*500*256` and it should be 'l2'-reduced along the first and second axes. By definition, the result is a `1*1*256` tensor. The following call to the numpy library demonstrates what the operator is doing:

```py
reduced = np.sqrt(np.sum(a=np.square(input), axis=tuple((0,1)), keepdims=1))
```

In order to implement it in cuda kernel, I first implemented it in python as follows:

```py
reduce_first = np.zeros([500, 256], dtype=np.float32)
reduce_second = np.zeros([256], dtype=np.float32)

res *= res

for i in range(res.shape[1]): #500
    for j in range(res.shape[2]): #256
        sum = 0
        for k in range(res.shape[0]): #400
            sum += res[k][i][j]
        reduce_first[i][j] = sum
    
#print(reduce_first.shape) #(500, 256)

for i in range(reduce_first.shape[1]): #256
    sum = 0
    for j in range(reduce_first.shape[0]): #500
        sum += reduce_first[j][i]
    reduce_second[i] = np.sqrt(sum)
```

The `reduce_second` tensor is verified to be identical to the above `reduced` tensor. Then I translate the python code naively to the following cuda kernel

```cpp
__global__ void ReduceL2Kernel(float* out, float* in, unsigned int first_dim, unsigned int second_dim, unsigned int third_dim){

    //400 * 500 * 256 -> 1 * 1 * 256
    //idz * idy * idx
    const int idz = blockIdx.z;//0~399
    const int idy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;//0~499
    const int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;//0~255

    if(idz >= first_dim || idy >= second_dim || idx >= third_dim) return;

    const int index = (idz * second_dim + idy) * third_dim + idx; //400*500*256
    in[index] *= in[index];

    //reduce along '400' axis
    float sum_first = 0.f;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < first_dim; i++)
        sum_first += in[(i * second_dim + idy) * third_dim + idx];
    out[idy * third_dim + idx] = sum_first;

    __threadfence();

    //reduce along '500' axis
    float sum_second = 0.f;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < second_dim; i++)
        sum_second += out[i * third_dim + idx];
    out[idx] = sqrtf(sum_second);
}
```

And the following is the cpp side code that calls the cuda kernel

```cpp
inline int CeilDiv(int a, int b) { return (a + b - 1) / b;}

dim3 block_dims{64, 16, 1};
dim3 grid_dims{CeilDiv(third_dim, 64), CeilDiv(second_dim, block_dims.y), first_dim};
ReduceL2Kernel<<<grid_dims, block_dims, 0, stream>>>((float*)out, (float*)in, first_dim, second_dim, third_dim);
```

The `out` tensor is then different from the `reduced` or the `reduce_second` tensor in python code. I can't figure out why, any correction is appreciated.

Comment: How different are the results? When doing doing a parallel reduction one floating point numbers you are normally not guaranteed bit-by-bit equal results to the sequential counterpart (or other parallel implementations) because parallel reduction algorithms mostly assume associativity which isn't there for floating point numbers (while it is for "real numbers").

Comment: @paleonix it's totally different, but I've found the bug, it's this line ```in[index] *= in[index]```, you can find the correct code in my own answer below.

Comment: @paleonix, I noticed that changing ```block_dims.x``` from ```64``` to ```32```(of course also the literal constant ```64```) givens wrong result, error check using ```cudaPeekAtLastError()``` shows noting, do you why?

Comment: `__threadfence()` is not a synchronization primitive. I.e. there is no guarantee that all elements in `out` are ready for the second part o the reduction. Also for the choice of doing sequential reductions you only need `256` threads. By having one thread per element you have multiple threads doing the same work and writing their results to the same destination.

Comment: See [What is the purpose of the threadfence intrinsic in CUDA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5232689/10107454).

Comment: Could you please provide a working version of sequential reduction code to this specific problem?  thanks!

Comment: I could, but do you really want that? 256 threads are far too few to get good performance from a GPU. You want to do a parallel reduction, i.e. use multiple threads (a warp or block for ease of implementation) to cooperatively work on each sum.

Comment: @paleonix, It's nice if you can provide both, but firstly I just want to figure out the correct code of sequential reduction, performance is my next step. I don't quite understand the sentence "By having one thread per element you have multiple threads doing the same work and writing their results to the same destination", could you elaborate this with concrete lines of code? Also the phrase "atomically mark a flag" in the link you posted is unclear to me and it's nice if you can explain this with code, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

The correct way of implementing the reducel2 operator naively is as follows:

```cpp
__global__ void ReduceL2Kernel(float* out, float* in, unsigned int first_dim, unsigned int second_dim, unsigned int third_dim){

    //400 * 500 * 256 -> 1 * 1 * 256
    //idz * idy * idx
    const int idz = blockIdx.z;//0~399
    const int idy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;//0~499
    const int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;//0~255

    if(idz >= first_dim || idy >= second_dim || idx >= third_dim) return;

    const int index = (idz * second_dim + idy) * third_dim + idx; //400*500*256
    //in[index] *= in[index];

    //reduce along '400' axis
    float sum_first = 0.f;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < first_dim; i++)
        sum_first += in[(i * second_dim + idy) * third_dim + idx] * in[(i * second_dim + idy) * third_dim + idx];
    out[idy * third_dim + idx] = sqrtf(sum_first);

    __threadfence();

    //reduce along '500' axis
    float sum_second = 0.f;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < second_dim; i++)
        sum_second += out[i * third_dim + idx] * out[i * third_dim + idx];
    out[idx] = sqrtf(sum_second);
}
```